# Spark job is taking more time with more(increased) memory

Tags: hadoop, time, apache-spark

**Why Spark job is taking more time with more(increased) memory.**

**Scenario**:In 3 node Spark cluster, I am running a spark job which reads records from files and writes it to Cassandra.Spark job takes around 1.5 minutes with application memory **512MB** and driver memory of **256MB** .whereas when I increased the application memory and driver memory to **2gb** and **1gb** respectively,spark job takes around 1.9 minutes to complete.

In both cases number of cores are 8.

Below is the GC log:

2.427: [GC [PSYoungGen: 132096K->18186K(153600K)] 132096K->18258K(503296K), 0.0286130 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs]

9.122: [GC [PSYoungGen: 135158K->21493K(153600K)] 135230K->24832K(503296K), 0.0614060 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.06, real=0.06 secs]

338.579: [GC [PSYoungGen: 153589K->21489K(153600K)] 156928K->51431K(503296K), 0.0619670 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.02, real=0.06 secs]

With **increased  memory**, Spark job should take less time,**but why it is taking more time?**

Comment: Are you needlessly caching objects? I've found that when I overuse cache() or persist() it sometimes gets slower. if that's the case, then when you give the application more memory maybe it's spending the extra time needlessly pulling stuff into memory because now it has the memory to waste?

Comment: No, I am not caching objects and also I have set the the conf parameter "spark.storage.memoryFraction" to  "0.4",which has decreased  the cache memory.

Comment: What does Spark UI show? Where does the tasks take time to complete

Comment: Is *Spark*, in the first experiment, using *all* of the assigned memory?

Comment: When I execute my program in SBT using similar settings, it seems to take longer to allocate/cleaning the memories when I set higher application and driver memory.

Comment: @hadooped, after increasing memory, spark job is taking more time for both read and write operations but it's taking more time for the write operation.

Comment: @Abhinandan do you see any gc time?

Comment: @MikelUrkia No.I am passing arguments for the spark job while submitting.

Comment: @hadooped Where I can see gc time?Addition to this I have set the configuration  parameter as: "spark.storage.memoryFraction" to 0.4 which has decreased the cache memory.

Comment: Can anyone else  help me with this problem?

Comment: @Abhinandan you can see gc time in the SPARK UI. Usually it will start on http://<driver>:4040

Comment: @hadooped I have added GC log above.